# add newly VMSS to existing backendpool of ApplicationGateway in Azure ARM

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-application-gateway, azure-vm-scale-set

As I am new to Azure ARM template, I would like to add newly created VMSS to existing backendpool of ApplicationGateway in Azure ARM; I am following this official link [Add VMSS in backendpool of ApplicationGateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#create-a-scale-set-that-references-an-application-gateway)

but while doing that I am getting this below error:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 07:17:14 PM - The deployment
> 'Test-APP' failed with error(s).  Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
> Status Message: Cannot parse the request. (Code: InvalidRequestFormat)
>
> - Could not find member 'ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPools' on object of type  'VMScaleSetNetworkInterfaceIPConfiguration'. Path
>   'Properties.UpdateGroups[0].NetworkProfile.networkI
>   nterfaceConfigurations[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPools',
>   line 1, position 671. (Code:InvalidJson) CorrelationId:
>   1234576-7tt2-49r1-b4d4-517b345691aa At line:8 char:1
>
> - New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzu
>   ```
>
> reResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

Any update on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below cmdlet's to add the new VMSS as backend address pool for existing application gateway using either PowerShell or Azure CLI.

- Power shell cmdlet to add new VMSS as backend pool :

  ```
  Add-AzApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool
  -ApplicationGateway <PSApplicationGateway>
  -Name <String>
  [-BackendIPAddresses <String[]>]
  [-BackendFqdns <String[]>]
  [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
  [-WhatIf]
  [-Confirm]
  [<CommonParameters>]
  ```

Here is the reference document for the above [power shell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-azapplicationgatewaybackendaddresspool?view=azps-6.3.0)

- Azure CLI to add new VMSS as backend pool :

  ```
  az network application-gateway address-pool create --gateway-name
                                                      --name
                                                      --resource-group
                                                      [--no-wait]
                                                      [--servers]
                                                      [--subscription]
  ```

Here is the reference document for the above [AzureCLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/address-pool?view=azure-cli-latest)